# How do I find the count of multiple words in a text file?

Tags: linux, shell

I am able to find the number of times a word occurs in a text file, like in Linux we can use:

```
cat filename|grep -c tom
```

My question is, how do I find the count of multiple words like "tom" and "joe" in a text file.

Comment: grep counts lines, not words.  Does a line with `tomtom` on it count as one or as two?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Multiple counts, one per every word you specified? Sum of counts for all words you specified? What is "word" - as tchrist already mentioned, your example counts number of lines that match a regexp, not number of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a couple names, regular expressions is the way to go on this one.  At first I thought it was as simple as just a grep count on the regular expression of joe or tom, but fount that this did not account for the scenario where tom and joe are on the same line (or tom and tom for that matter).

test.txt:

```
tom is really really cool!  joe for the win!
tom is actually lame.


$ grep -c '\<\(tom\|joe\)\>' test.txt
2
```

As you can see from the test.txt file, 2 is the wrong answer, so we needed to account for names being on the same line.

I then used grep -o to show only the part of a matching line that matches the pattern where it gave the correct pattern matches of tom or joe in the file.  I then piped the results into number of lines into wc for the line count.

```
$ grep -o '\(joe\|tom\)' test.txt|wc -l
       3
```

3...the correct answer!  Hope this helps

Comment: I modified the regular expression a little bit to handle the case of tomtom.  Nice test case...thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The really hard test case would involve overlapping matches on the original words. :)  For example, if the words you wanted the count of were `cure`, `core`, `rely`, `lysis`, `island`, `land`, and `dish`, then you would get 2 hits on things like `insecurely` and `outlandish` and 3 hits on things like `islandish` and `corelysis`. A naïve approach would count those as only one apiece. This is not fun with one regex, but pretty easy with N of them, one per word.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so first split the file into words, then `sort` and `uniq`:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '\n' < testdata | sort | uniq -c
```

<strike>You use `uniq`:</strike>

```
sort filename | uniq -c
```

Comment: Whoops. For next time, how about I read the question properly? *facepalm*

Comment: this (splitting in words, selecting, counting) would have been my option too. when substituting things that are not `:alnum:` to `\n` you may need take care of language differences, like in `cat Castilian/*.txt | tr A-Z a-z | tr -cs '[a-záóúíéñ]' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

Answer (score 1):

Use awk:

```
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    count[$i]++
}
END {
    for (i in count)
        print count[i], i
}
```

This will produce a complete word frequency count for the input.
Pipe tho output to `grep` to get the desired fields

```
awk -f w.awk input | grep -E 'tom|joe'
```

BTW, you do not need `cat` in your example, most programs that acts as filters can take the filename as an parameter; hence it's better to use

```
grep -c tom filename
```

if not, there is a strong possibility that people will start throwing [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) at you ;-)

Comment: "most programs that acts as filters can take the filename as an parameter" ... and even when they don't, you can still use input redirection (like `grep -c tom < filename`).

Comment: `grep -c` does not look for words, hence you have to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one:

```
cat txt | tr -s '[:punct:][:space:][:blank:]'| tr '[:punct:][:space:][:blank:]' '\n\n\n' | tr -s '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

**UPDATE**

A shell script solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name="$2"
string="$1"

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
  then
   echo "Usage: $0 <pattern to search> <file_name>"
   exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$file_name" ]
 then
  echo "file \"$file_name\" does not exist, or is not a regular file"
  exit 2
fi

line_no_list=("")
curr_line_indx=1
line_no_indx=0
total_occurance=0

# line_no_list contains loc k the line number loc k+1 the number
# of times the string occur at that line
while read line
 do
  flag=0
  while [[ "$line" == *$string* ]]
   do
    flag=1
    line_no_list[line_no_indx]=$curr_line_indx
    line_no_list[line_no_indx+1]=$((line_no_list[line_no_indx+1]+1))
    total_occurance=$((total_occurance+1))
# remove the pattern "$string" with a null" and recheck
    line=${line/"$string"/}
  done
# if we have entered the while loop then increment the
# line index to access the next array pos in the next
# iteration
  if (( flag == 1 ))
   then
    line_no_indx=$((line_no_indx+2))
  fi
  curr_line_indx=$((curr_line_indx+1))
done < "$file_name"


echo -e "\nThe string \"$string\" occurs \"$total_occurance\" times"
echo -e "The string \"$string\" occurs in \"$((line_no_indx/2))\" lines"
echo "[Occurence # : Line Number : Nos of Occurance in this line]: "

for ((i=0; i<line_no_indx; i=i+2))
 do
  echo "$((i/2+1)) : ${line_no_list[i]} : ${line_no_list[i+1]} "
done

echo
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The sample you gave does *not* search for *words* "tom". It will count "atom" and "bottom" and many more.
2. Grep searches for *regular expressions*. Regular expression that matches word "tom" or "joe" is

   ```
   \<\(tom\|joe\)\>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could do regexp,

```
 cat filename |tr ' ' '\n' |grep -c -e "\(joe\|tom\)"
```

Comment: Your solution even accounts for joe and tom on the same line.  Nice!

Comment: @Travis: However, it erroneously counts `tomtom` only once, even though even my grandpa can see that there are two `tom`s present.

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot about grep -f:

```
cat filename | grep -fc names
```

AWK solution:

Assuming the names are in a file called `names`:

```
cat filename | awk 'NR==FNR {h[NR] = $1;ct[i] = 0; cnt=NR} NR !=FNR {for(i=1;i<=cnt;++i) if(match($0,h[i])!=0) ++ct[i] } END {for(i in h) print h[i], ct[i]}' names -
```

Note that your original grep doesn't search for words.  e.g.

```
$ echo tomorrow | grep -c tom
1
```

You need `grep -w`

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk -vRS='[^[:alpha:]]+' '{print}' | grep -c '^(tom|joe|bob|sue)$'
```

The gawk program sets the record separator to anything non-alphabetic, so every word will end up on a separate line. Then grep counts lines that match one of the words you want exactly.

We use gawk because the POSIX awk doesn't allow regex record separator.

For brevity, you can replace `'{print}'` with `1` - either way, it's an Awk program that simply prints out all input records ("is `1` true? it is? then do the default action, which is `{print}`.")

Answer (score 0):

To find all hits in all lines

```
echo "tom is really really cool!  joe for the win!
tom is actually lame." | akw '{i+=gsub(/tom|joe/,"")} END {print i}'
3
```

This will count "tomtom" as 2 hits.